VBA Data Retrieval and Copy in new tab
I am trying to create a 'Master Workbook' in Excel that will collect and handle data from other files.
The main worksheet will have the list of files in Column A, names that I want for new worksheets in Column B, and a button that will go through this list of files. (I want this to accomodate a varying amount of files, could be 1 or 10 or 40).
When the button is clicked, it will open each file, and copy that data into a NEW tab in the Master Workbook. If the tab already exists, it will clear that tab's data and replace it with the new data.
I am stuck on creating the new sheets. I have seen ways to create new sheets from a range, but I want to be able to vary the # of files, it won't always be a set number of files.
I have put my VBA code below. I need to create new sheets, rename them after the corresponding file, open the file, extract the data and place it into a new tab.

Sub RunThroughList()
    Dim numFiles As Integer ' define a variable
    Dim currFile As String ' current file name
    Dim devMode As Integer ' dev mode 0 = false; 1 = true; when enabled, msgbox will be presented
    devMode = 0
    
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
        numFiles = getLastRow(.Sheets("MAIN SHEET"), "A") ' get last row of "Main Sheet", column "A"
        If devMode = 1 Then
            MsgBox (CStr(numFiles))
        End If
        For i = 2 To numFiles ' for each file name in the list, skip the first row because it is a header
            currFile = .Sheets("MAIN SHEET").Cells(i, 1).Value ' get file name found in column "A" (1). variable 'i' represents the row we are currently searching in
            MsgBox (currFile) ' msgbox current file name
            ' create new sheet in this workbook
            ' rename new sheet in this workbook
            ' open currfile
            ' extract data
            ' place in new tab
        Next i ' continue to the next file, if there are more
    End With
End Sub

EDIT: [Stack says I can't upload pictures yet so it provided a link] 1


Create new sheet with Sheets.Add in For loop

Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.UsedRange property (Excel)


Workbook.Close method (Excel)


Range.Clear method (Excel)


Sheets.Add method (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub MergeWorkbooks()
    Dim i As Long, sFileName As String ' current file name
    Dim dataWK As Workbook, oWK As Workbook, sPath As String, sShtName As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet, mainSht As Worksheet
    Set oWK = ThisWorkbook
    sPath = oWK.Path & "\"
    Set mainSht = oWK.Sheets("MAIN SHEET")
    lastRow = mainSht.Cells(mainSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' for each file name in the list, skip the first row because it is a header
        sFileName = mainSht.Cells(i, 1).Value '**
        sShtName = mainSht.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ' Check if the file exist
        MsgBox sFileName
        If Len(Dir(sFileName)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Can't find file: " & sFileName
        Else
            Set oSht = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set oSht = oWK.Sheets(sShtName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If oSht Is Nothing Then
                ' create new sheet with name from Col B
                Set oSht = oWK.Sheets.Add(after:=oWK.Sheets(oWK.Sheets.Count))
                oSht.Name = sShtName
            Else
                ' clear dest. sheet
                oSht.Cells.Clear
            End If
            ' open file
            Set dataWK = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
            ' copy data
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy oSht.Range("A1")
            ' close file
            dataWK.Close False
        End If
    Next i ' continue to the next file, if there are more
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub


Thanks so much for your quick reply!! I am running into an issue with this part " If Len(Dir(sFileName)) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Can't find file: " & sFileName"                                                                                 I am getting an error 52

Do you try to access files on cloud or local disk?

They are on my local disk right now, in my downloads.

What's the error text? Is it on Win or MacOS?

I am on windows. When I run it says "Run-time error '52': bad name or file number." If i click 'debug' it highlights this line " If Len(Dir(sFileName)) = 0 Then"

Add MsgBox sFileName before If to check its value.

I copied MsgBox sFileName and put it a line before the If Len,, still same error

What did you see on popup windon (by MsgBox sFileName)? Please check updated code.

It says https://d.docs.live.net/979df815a5fa6c7e/Documents\C:name of the first file I have listed (in cell A2)

Pls edit your original post to upload an image.

edit done, it is shown below my code, link should be at very bottom of my post.

OP doesn't clarify the file name with folder path on Col A. Please try the updated code ( marked with ** ).

Each time I try to run the macro, it says it cannot find any of the files I have listed in column A? I just copied link directy from location in my files.
